# ASP .NET WebApi POST method keeping request body in memory

Tags: c#, http, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

I've noticed I had big memory usage on my server, so when I inspected it I saw the IIS process takes 200-400 megabytes of memory at all times after receiving one request. After some checking I stripped my web service method completely to this, and the problem persists:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]JToken json)
{
return Ok();
}
```

Usually the arriving `json` is pretty big, but to my knowledge​ the WebApi should dispose of it after returning `Ok`. Is that related to IIS cache or some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but to my knowledge​ the WebApi should dispose of it after returning Ok.

That's not necessarily true. What will happen after you `return Ok();` is that the `json` variable will fall out of scope. And when a variable falls out of scope it becomes elligible for garbage collection. This doesn't mean at all that will be disposed immediately. It will be disposed when the next GC occurs. Which might happen if there's memory pressure for example. It is something that the CLR takes care of and you shouldn't be concerned much about. It is pretty normal to have the worker process in IIS take some memory. On Server OSes, the GC is optimized so that it runs only when necessary to clean up resources to avoid wasting precious CPU cycles.

Comment: The problem is, it stays like that for a long time, and with other services consuming memory as well, the server starts to stutter.

Comment: As soon as there's memory pressure GC should occur and release it. Do not be concerned about it. It is perfectly normal to stay like that for a long time.